# Trigger key press on computer

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi this is actually a pretty simple question but not sure if there’s a simple answer.

But is it possible for a webpage to trigger a key press on a machine. Like hitting the A key or maybe the shift?

Comment: This is not duplicate of the other question because what  I want is the page to being able to press buttons, let’s say then windows button so the start menu of windows pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to triggering DOM events on a web page, you can use the `Event` object. A detailed description of the API can be found here [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

A simple example:

```
var clickEvent = new Event('click');
var elem = document.getElementById('event-target');

elem.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

There is also the `KeyboardEvent` class for triggering keyboard events. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). It's first parameter is the type of event, and the second is an object describing the event. Example usage:

```
var aKeyDownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: 'a'});
var elem = document.getElementById('event-target');

elem.dispatchEvent(aKeyDownEvent);
```

Keep in mind there isn't universal browser support for these features.

Comment: Can you add more detail that the duplicate question doesn't already show in the answers? Dispatching events is good, but you haven't touched on dispatching a keyboard event

Comment: You're right, i'll edit

Comment: But I’m not sure if you understood the question correctly then. Because I want the page to be able to press buttons, let’s say then windows button so the start menu of windows pops up.

Comment: You can't do that, that would be a huge security issue